# "user NOT in sudoers" when using RealmD, SSSD

Tags: 16.04, sudo, active-directory, sssd

Recently began joining our Ubuntu server to the domain for authentication. For the most part I have been successful and believe to have all configs identical on each system. However, ran into two today that will allow authentication but not SUDO access. I have verified and double verified correct sudoers config (at least confirmed it is the same as the working systems), realmd config and SSSD config.

As you can see, here is the log from a session over SSH and then attempting to go SUDO. States that user is not in the sudoers group. Further down you will find the sudoers file output and several other relevant snippets of config. Please advise on next steps to troubleshoot. It is much appreciated.

```
    Oct 22 16:04:58 server-1 sshd[8701]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.15.25  user=MYDOMAIN\smithj
Oct 22 16:04:58 server-1 sshd[8701]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.15.25 user=MYDOMAIN\smithj
Oct 22 16:04:59 server-1 sshd[8701]: Accepted password for MYDOMAIN\\smithj from 192.168.15.25 port 7438 ssh2
Oct 22 16:04:59 server-1 sshd[8701]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user MYDOMAIN\smithj by (uid=0)
Oct 22 16:04:59 server-1 systemd-logind[1323]: New session 6 of user smithj.
Oct 22 16:05:00 server-1 systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user smithj by (uid=0)
Oct 22 16:05:06 server-1 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname=smithj uid=535028654 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/1 ruser=smithj rhost=  user=smithj
Oct 22 16:05:06 server-1 sudo: pam_sss(sudo:auth): authentication success; logname=smithj uid=535028654 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/1 ruser=smithj rhost= user=smithj
Oct 22 16:05:07 server-1 sudo: smithj : user NOT in sudoers ; TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/MYDOMAIN/smithj ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/su
```

Sudoers file:

```
# As file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.di

#AD Domain Groups and Users
%domain\ admins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Output of "id smithj"

```
uid=535028654(smithj) gid=535000513(domain users) groups=535000513(domain users),535000512(domain admins)
```

Output of "getent group 'domain admins':

```
domain admins:*:535000512:smithj
```

Output of "getent passwd smithj":

```
smithj:*:535028654:535000513:Smith, John:/home/MYDOMAIN/smithj:/bin/bash
```

SSSD.conf

```
    [sssd]
domains = mydomain.com
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/mydomain.com]
ad_domain = mydomain.com
krb5_realm = MYDOMAIN.COM
realmd_tags = joined-with-adcli
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/MYDOMAIN/%u
access_provider = simple
simple_allow_groups = Domain Admins
```

Realmd.conf

```
    [users]
default-home = /home/MYDOMAIN/%U
default-shell = /bin/bash
[active-directory]
default-client = sssd
os-name = Ubuntu Server
os-version = 16.04
[service]
automatic-install = no
[mydomain.com]
fully-qualified-names = no
automatic-id-mapping = yes
user-principal = yes
manage-system = no
```

Comment: So...apparently the specifying "%domain\ admins..." at the bottom of /etc/sudoers does not work. Simply moved it up above the "#includedir" line and it worked.

Comment: I don't feel like this is the real solution though. According to some documentation the lines below should be included...https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html#Including_other_files_from_within_sudoers